# Index not found on one to one assocation with doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: userTrack in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs
\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 110
```

File.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JJ\MainBundle\Entity\UserTrack", mappedBy="file", fetch="EAGER")
 * @JMS\Expose
 */
protected $user_track;
```

UserTrack.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JJ\MainBundle\Entity\File", inversedBy="user_track", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $file;
```

I can generate entites fine.
I can update my schema fine.
What gives?

Edit:

```
public function findRandomByUser(User $user)
{
    $pointer = rand(0, $user->getFiles()->count() - 1);
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
            SELECT f
            FROM MainBundle:File f
            WHERE f.user = :user
        ")
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setFirstResult($pointer)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $user->getId()
        ));
    return $query->getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: Can you please expose what code is triggering the problem? What's the stack trace?

Comment: @Ocramius added section

Comment: Did you validate all of your mappings with `doctrine:validate-schema` ?

Comment: @Ocramius Yes, doctrine:schema:validate showed me the solution, not sure how I've missed this awesome validator. Please answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please validate your schema with the `doctrine:validate-schema` command (`orm:validate-schema` when using only the ORM as standalone).

Problems like these in the `UnitOfWork` and in internals usually happen because of invalid mappings, typos and generally mistakes that the ORM does not validate at runtime because of the performance implications of the validation step.